# Grunt Read YAML Frontmatter

Tags: gruntjs, yaml

I have a Handlebars template (index.hbs) that usings YAML Front Matter.

```
---
title: "Hello World"
whatever: "Something else"
---

<div>etc.....</div>
```

Using Grunt, I want to return the 'title' that I can use in my grunt file. I started with just using `grunt.file.read('index.hbs')` but wasn't sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

See [grunt-matter](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-matter), that would meet your needs.